# Dialogue Flow send card response to all platform

Tags: json, dialogflow-es

Hi i want to send multiple cards to all platform in using dialogue flow.

my json is :

```
{

      "fulfillmentText": "This is a text response",
      "fulfillmentMessages": [
        {
          "card": {
            "title": "card title",
            "subtitle": "card text",
            "imageUri": "https://assistant.google.com/static/images/molecule/Molecule-Formation-stop.png",
            "buttons": [
              {
                "text": "button text",
                "postback": "https://assistant.google.com/"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
```

this one is not working , can someone suggest , how can i send json so that my muliple messages will show

Please help

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass those data in Your webhook fulfilment code,

```
agent.add(new Card({
        title: `Title: this is a card title`,
        imageUrl: imageUrl,
        text: `This is the body text of a card.  You can even use line\n  breaks and emoji! `,
        buttonText: 'This is a button',
        buttonUrl: linkUrl
      })
    );
```

You can check detailed description [here](https://github.com/dialogflow/fulfillment-actions-library-nodejs/blob/master/functions/index.js),